# what wifi modules exactly do?

Tags: wifi

Does it connect to server directly or connected to a router for data sharing or both?
well, I'm having hard time about understanding this issues. Does it can provide communication to the server directly or it need another device such as router to do it.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site!  Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to be about the Internet of Things, as defined in the [help center](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  If it is directly related to IoT, please [edit] your question to explain exactly how that is the case.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, I can't quite think of a sibling site where this would be on topic ... is this a hardware question? electronics? networking?

Comment: what is the level of your networking knowledge?